# Monit and private_pub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, shell, monit

to start the thin server with monit is just `start program = "/etc/init.d/thin start"`

but to start private_pub or faye is needed to bundle the rackup.

and how to stop the pid?

someone have a idea?

```
check process  private_pub_myapp
  with pidfile "/home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/tmp/pids/private_pub.pid"
  start program = "bundle exec rackup /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/config/private_pub.ru -s thin -E production" with timeout 90 seconds

  stop program = "kill -s TERM `cat /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/config/private_pub.yml`" with timeout 90 seconds
  if totalmem is greater than 200 MB for 2 cycles then restart # eating up memory?
  group private_pub_myapp
```

monit spitting out

> /conf.d/private_pub.conf:3: Warning: Program does not exist: 'bundle'
>   /etc/monit/conf.d/private_pub.conf:5: Warning: Program does not exist:
>   'kill'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need to give a full, absolute path when using Monit. For example `start program = "/usr/local/bin/bundle exec ..."` and similar. That said, I suspect this still won't work. You seem to be trying to cat the config YAML to find the PID to kill which is probably a copy-paste issue and you'll need to make sure your rackup config is actually writing out the PID file.